# Best way to add a call to a (Python) command line program in an R package?

Tags: r, command-line, package

I made an R package that, among other things, calls a python command line program with the following code:

```
py_loc = paste('C:/Python33/python.exe',system.file('exec', 'example.py', package='examplePackage'))
command <- paste(py_loc,"-e example")
```

It runs the program `example.py` in the `exec` folder of my `example` package with the Python executable `C:/Python33/python.exe`. Because I use Windows, and I want to share it with other Windows users (but also non-Windows users) I can't use rPython to write the code. 
The problem is that the `python.exe` will be located somewhere different for other users.

My idea was to add a `config` file where you can set the location of the Python executable, or to ask it as the input of the function. Is there a better way to add a call to a (Python) command line program in an R package?

Comment: Have you looked at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/findpython/index.html

Answer (score 1):

"rPython does not work on Windows yet. "
However the author of rPython wrote a version for Windows:
https://github.com/cjgb/rPython-win
Both rPython and rPython-win require that you install Python first, then "point" the R package to it.
I recently learned of another 'wrapper' package, PythonInR: https://bitbucket.org/Floooo/pythoninr/
I have not tried it out but the documentation looks substantial.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make a platform dependent wrapper function which accepts the path to python executable, the python script and the command line arguments to the script. This should create the proper batch/shell command string and run it with the `system` command in R. It will allow you to capture the output from the batch/shell process and you can further manipulate this output in R.

Answer (score 0):

Try [rPython](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rPython/index.html) for platform independent calls, as long as Python and related modules are installed.

See [Examples](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rPython/rPython.pdf)