# How can the Python runtime be embedded in an R package that runs on Windows

Tags: python, r, gcc

We wish to create an R package that wraps the Python runtime and is 'dependency free' (e.g. one need not install Python for the R package to work).  There is already a package that allows R to call Python (CRAN package rPython) but it requires that Python be installed on the target machine.  We would like all dependencies to be installed when the envisioned package is installed via the standard R package install mechanism.  I forked rPython and created this variation: https://github.com/brucehoff/rWithPython.    The package works on Unix and Mac.  It downloads and builds the Python source and then accesses the Python runtime from R.  By using a *static* version of libpython it builds a shared object that can be installed on another machine without leaving any dependencies behind.   The problem is how to get it to work on Windows.  On windows, R packages are built using "R Tools" (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) which uses the cygwin/mingw stack.  I tried running configure/make as on Unix, but it fails.  I then tried linking a static libpython that I built on a Windows box using Visual Studio.  Python is very helpful, providing instructions for changing the MVS build to create a static library:
PCBuild\readme.txt says, in part:

> The solution has no configuration for static libraries. However it is
>       easy to build a static library instead of a DLL. You simply have to set
>       the "Configuration Type" to "Static Library (.lib)" and alter the
>       preprocessor macro "Py_ENABLE_SHARED" to "Py_NO_ENABLE_SHARED". You may
>       also have to change the "Runtime Library" from "Multi-threaded DLL
>       (/MD)" to "Multi-threaded (/MT)".

This works great and I get a static library for python.  However when I try to link the library under cygwin/rtools the linker gives an error:

`gcc -m32 -I"C:/bin/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"  -I"C:/Python35/Include" -I"C:/Python35/PC"   -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c pycall.c -o pycall.o
gcc -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o rWithPython.dll tmp.def pycall.o -LC:/Python35/PCbuild/win32 -lpython35 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/bin/R/bin/i386 -lR
c:/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Python35/PCbuild/win32/libpython35.a(C:/hgpy/cpython/PCbuild/obj//win32_Release/pythoncore/getbuildinfo.obj): Recognised but unhandled machine type (0x14c) in Import Library Format archive
pycall.o:pycall.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to '_imp__Py_Initialize'
pycall.o:pycall.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to '_imp__PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
pycall.o:pycall.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to '_imp__Py_Finalize'
pycall.o:pycall.c:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to '_imp__PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
pycall.o:pycall.c:(.text+0x8c): undefined reference to '_imp__PyImport_AddModule'
pycall.o:pycall.c:(.text+0x95): undefined reference to '_imp__PyModule_GetDict'
pycall.o:pycall.c:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to '_imp__PyDict_GetItemString'
pycall.o:pycall.c:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to '_imp__PyUnicode_AsUTF8String'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rWithPython'`

From what I've read "machine type" 0x14c is "Intel 386 or later, and compatible processors", i.e. the most common/expected machine type.  So I'm guessing the error is a red herring, the problem is an incompatibility between compilers, not machines.

Any suggestions on how to proceed are appreciated!!

---- UPDATE ----
I verified that I *can* build/link (1) when linking in the library(ies) that are part of the standard Windows Python installation and (2) when building from source using MS Visual Studio, without modifying the build in any way.  The problem is replicated as soon as I modify the Visual Studio build settings to produce a static library (python35.lib) following the guidelines in PCbuild\readme.txt.  Those guidelines are a bit ambiguous.  I will probe further, but if anyone has had success generating a static Python library in MS VS, please let me know!

---- ANOTHER UPDATE ----
We have a solution to this question:
https://github.com/Sage-Bionetworks/PythonEmbedInR
(The code is open source, under the GPL-3 license.)

You can see how we solved the problem of running on Windows:
https://github.com/Sage-Bionetworks/PythonEmbedInR/blob/master/configure.win

In short we do not try to compile from source or make a static library, rather we use Python's 'embeddable zip' and make sure its libraries are on the search path for our application.  It seems to work great!

Comment: This related question may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202876/best-way-to-add-a-call-to-a-python-command-line-program-in-an-r-package

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the Py_NO_ENABLE_SHARED define in your application code as well.  Basically, anywhere the Python.h file is included.  If not present, the include file assumes you have linked with a .dll and acts accordingly (and incorrectly.)